# Facebook Exception when Creating Relationship via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to establish a Business On Behalf Of relationship,I follow this document,[Business on behalf of](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/v12.0), ended up getting an error -`You couldn't create the client business on behalf of your client successfully` error code- `42004`

the error occurred when I call this endpoint

```
curl -i -X POST \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/<PARTNER_BM_ID>/managed_businesses?existing_client_business_id=<CLIENT_BM_ID>&access_token=<USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

PARTNER_BM_ID - my apps business manager

CLIENT_BM_ID - business manager of client connected

USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN - access token of the client

the error is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/v12.0), but the error message is not helping me to debug what is the issue.